# Why don't I get Google Talk notifications on my Android from people using iPhones?

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-talk, ios

I'm using the stock Google Talk app. I don't seem to have a problem getting Google Talk notifications from people on a PC.

However, I don't get any notifications at all from people using iPhones (or, at least certain apps).  I can still see their messages in my Google Talk app if I open it manually.  I just don't get any notifications when a message arrives.

Why would the *other party's* device affect my ability to get notifications?  Is there any way to fix this, or is there a third party Android app that handles notifications better than the stock one?

My device is a Verizon Galaxy S3 (SCH-I535) running CyanogenMod 10.1-d2vzw (Android 4.2.1).

Comment: Interesting observation.